# Android Studio autocomplete wrap object in another object

Tags: android, android-studio, autocomplete, ide

So is my existing code:

```
fun getAllPeople(): List<People> {
  return peopleDao.getAll()
  ...
}
```

and I want to wrap the `List<People>` in a `LiveData` object.

When I start typing in the front, autocomplete gives me the suggestion for `LiveData` [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCOqa.jpg),
but then when I hit enter it completes to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jab2H.jpg).
I know I can then type `<` and move to the end and type `>`.

But isn't there an easy way to wrap something with another object correctly?

Comment: Write `LIveData<>` then inside your `<>` write your list.

Comment: The thing is I wrote it as `List<People>` first and now want to implement it as `LiveData`. I know I can write the `<>` myself, but I thought maybe there was an easy way in Android Studio I'm missing.

Comment: Well, I understood that from the question. What I'm suggesting is to write Live data first then inside that write list.

Comment: So your suggestion is to delete what I've already written and write it again but start with the `LiveData` first. I know I can do that. My question is if there is an easy way to use autocomplete to wrap it in another object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this for your current selection with a custom live template:

1. Go to Settings -> Editor -> Live Templates
2. Under Android, add a new template (Alt+Insert or the green 'plus' button on the right)
3. Give an abbreviation and a description to your template
4. Set the template text to `LiveData<$SELECTION$>`
5. Set the applicable contexts to Java and Kotlin
6. Click Apply

Now when you select your `List<People>` and use "Surround with Live Template" (Ctrl+Alt+J on Windows/Linux, Cmd+Alt+J on Mac by default), you can choose your custom template from the list and watch as the selected declaration becomes `LiveData<List<People>>`.

Tip: You can also use the "Extend Selection" shortcut to more easily select the declaration (Ctrl+W on Win/Linux, Alt+Up on Mac by default).